# Modelling in R and scoring in SQL

Tags: mysql, export, scoring

I have a question about modelling in R and scoring in SQL.

I made two models - a regression and a random forest - and I want to use the models for scoring in a production system in (My)sql. Right now the only way I can think of is saving the coefficients from the regression and then read them in SQL and perform the scoring from this. I don't know how to use the random forest model in SQL.

Is there any easier way to export score code to from models made in R to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to rewrite the `random forest` algorithm,you can get processed information from Mysql with`RMysql`,then read by R.in R get your models made.

Comment: Thank you Leal.li. Maybe I misunderstand your answer but I think I need the other way around. I already made the models in R and want to export the score code from R to SQL.